# MediaWiki foreground not rendering tabs in content section

Tags: godaddy, mediawiki, javascript, css

We are having issues getting the foreground or foundation skins in MediaWiki to render any tabs in the content section of our pages.  This site is a demo, hosted on GoDaddy, but we have also tried clean installs Fedora locally and Linode.

All the applicable CSS and JS seems to be loading correctly, and there are no obvious errors in the logs.  The skin/theme does correctly render the navbar section at the top of the pages.  Maybe we are doing something wrong in the syntax or there is another step to enabling the skin/theme we are missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

https://protocol96.com/mw/Main_Page

Comment: First, you have to fix the TLS certificate error. This will cause a variety of problems, such as content not being loaded properly.

Comment: Can you post the error you see?  We have a wildcard cert on the domain and from Chrome and Firefox we are all good...at least not showing any errors.

Comment: Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from wiki.protocol96.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server could not prove that it is wiki.protocol96.com; its security certificate is from *.prod.iad2.secureserver.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Comment: I understand.  That is coming from the subdomain redirect from GoDaddy.  The actual wiki instance is at https://protocol96.com/mw/Main_Page.  The SSL checkers will validate correctly there.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I don't see any issues loading that URL. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this one figured out.  Turned on debug logging, and the cache directory was included in the configuration ($IP/cache), but not writeable.

Thank you for your help.